# Problem Allocating Logical from Class(*) using Source in Fortran

Tags: fortran, boolean, allocation, intel-fortran

Is the following valid Fortran

```
    Program LogicalAllocation
        class(*), pointer :: bool

        allocate(bool, source=.false.)
        select type(bool)
        type is (logical)
            Print *, bool
        end select
    End Program LogicalAllocation
```

On my intel fortran oneapi version 2023.0.0.25839 this code will print 'T' or 'F' seemingly at random.

Comment: I confirm your findings with ifort. It produces F every time with gfortran and nagfor, though. With ifort, the problem appears to be only with LOGICAL type.

Comment: I think it's a compiler bug in ifort (but not ifx). With any other type than logical it seems to work OK. With a logical type, it's as if the "source=" part wasn't there and the memory location was allocated but not assigned a value, so evoking undefined behaviour. Not sure where you report intel compiler bugs.

Comment: Intel bugs are reported in the user forum or used to be also possible in the premier support site, but almost everyone probably has the free version now.

Comment: Although probably not relevant in this case, please be sure to add `implicit none` to all examples, even though it's less "minimal": it's a significant simplification to anyone looking at the code. As others have commented (and with whom I agree) if you're seeing something other than a false value, that's a compiler bug. Are you after confirmation of that, or is there some important concept about whether there's subtle standard violation that you're keen to have addressed?

Comment: FWIW, I don't reproduce with ifort 2023.2 or 2021. @lastchance, which version for you?

Comment: I find the same problems as the OP with ifort 2021.8.0: I don't have any later version, I'm afraid. There are no problems with ifx (the other, newer, compiler in the oneapi suite).

Comment: Oh, @lastchance, it was 2021.8.0 of the 2021s I tried: no trues in a couple dozen attempts. Guess we'll have to leave it to Intel to explore.

Comment: No, that was all I wanted to confirm. Obviously there are easy work arounds. I appreciate it. And will do @ adding implicit none in the future. I'll attempt to report in the user forum.

Comment: Also in my original case and my test case it was heavily biased one (but different directions). Sometimes I had to rebuild in order for it to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visitors. It should be valid Fortran syntax, and it seems to be a compiler bug.